# Is 'be' before associated with always omitted?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

There's a sentence from my book that makes me wonder about the construction.

> My work is concerned with the structure and function of the organic
> molecules **associated with** living organisms.

At first, I thought it was a passive phrase or the past simple of the verb *associate* and I wanted to make sure which part of speech that phrase is, and according to Cambridge Dictionary it's a phrasal verb *be associated with*.

Then why the writer of the book omitted **be**? Can it be applied to all cases (phrasal verbs with be) or is it just a special case (common writing) when you're allowed to omit 'be'?

Comment: "Associated with living organism" isn't correct; it should be "...living organism**s**" (using the plural to indicate the general object of study).

Comment: @randomhead thanks. I had a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two omitted words. The full phrase would be, "*...the organic molecules [**which are** associated with a living organism].*"

The part in brackets ([]) is a *defining (or "identifying") subject relative clause*. There's a rule that if a defining subject relative clause has a "be"-verb as the main verb, both the relative pronoun and the "be"-verb may be omitted. This is such a common omission that native speakers tend to omit these words more often than we include them -- the omission is more natural than the full phrase.

That is probably enough to answer your question, but you also mentioned this looks like a passive structure, so I'll talk about that too.

In this case, it's not passive. It's a "be"-verb followed by a participial adjective. There are a lot of adjectives formed from past participles:

- The walls weren't bare; they were ***painted***.
- That door has been ***closed*** for years.
- The barrel is ***filled*** to the top with rice.

While all of these examples, including your original example, have the structure: ***"be"-verb + past participle***, they are not passive. You can convince yourself it's true by trying to add "by someone" to the end, and then either the meaning changes, or the sentences don't even make sense.

Comment: This phenomenon is called **whiz-deletion**, by the way.

Comment: @stangdon Thanks for the new-to-me terminology! Here's an interesting article about an exception I didn't know about and its modern consequences: http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650

Answer (score 0):

There is no omitted word.

The phrase "associated with living organisms" is a participle phrase. It modifies the noun "organic molecules"

It would be incorrect to put "be" (or is, or are etc).  The main verb is "is concerned with". You can't have a second main verb in the clause.

You could use a relative clause to modify the mound

> ... organic molecules that are associated with ....

That has the same meaning as the participle form.